# Why is my Selenium selector pulling a dict? (Django/Python 3.8)

Tags: python, django, selenium, dictionary, selector

I've just updated selenium in my django app on PythonAnywhere. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def Synonym():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get("https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/test")
    test = browser.find_element_by_class_name("logo").text
    browser.quit()

    return test
```

But it gives me an error:

**AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'**

When I grab it without the .text this is what it gives me:

```
{'ELEMENT': '0.3567871003333163-1'}
```

I'm using a paid account and should be able to access any site. Sidenote: is there a way to stop selenium from making /tmp/ files and folders?

Thanks!

Comment: That is strange, it should not have happened. Please put a delay `time.sleep(5)` before `test = browser.find_element_by_class_name("logo").text` and see if that works.

Comment: I added `time.sleep(5)` and am still getting the error.

Comment: I am using Pycharm and have this code `link = "https://www.synonym.com/synonyms/test"
driver.get(link)
test = driver.find_element_by_class_name("logo").text
print(test)
` and I got `SYNONYM.COM` as an output.

Comment: I should be getting that. I don't know why I'm getting a dict instead?

Comment: Just run your code using the newest system image on PythonAnywhere and Python 3.8 and got 'SYNONYM.COM' as the return value.

Comment: That did it!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for me on PythonAnywhere was to update the system image:
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ChangingSystemImage

Answer courtesy of caseneuve!